# Creating custom info window in swift with the Google maps iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, sdk, infowindow

I have created a xib and a view controller, and want to display it a customised info window for a marker in swift. After searching on the Internet I have found an old tutorial in OBJ-C however this will not help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement the [markerInfoWindow method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a961e81669891377c9ebee752ce53340f) from GMSMapViewDelegate

Sample implementation to show an custom info window in Swift:

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
        var infoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as CustomInfoWindow
        infoWindow.label.text = "\(marker.position.latitude) \(marker.position.longitude)"
        return infoWindow
 }
```

You can visit [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMaps-Swift/blob/master/GoogleMapSwift/ViewController.swift) for detail implementation.

Depends on how you want your info window looks like, you can change the background color by doing `infoWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`, or change the shape of your info window by doing `infoWindow.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f`, or even add an image by doing `infoWindow.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")`.

Comment: Is there anyway of making this look more like an info window instead of just a square box.

Comment: Please see my edited answer @user3280937, it really depends on how you want your info window looks like, you can do a lot of customization in your xib file or do in code.