# Swift - how to add custom fields to markers in Google Maps SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I try to build app with maps, and I want to have additional info in markers. Documentation offers only 2 properties `title` and `snippet`. It looks like this

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.snippet = "Population: 8,174,100"
london.map = mapView
```

For example, I want to add field `rating` to each marker to display average rating for place.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can implement a custom info window, so when user click on a marker, it will show the rating and additional information about a selected place. You can see [this Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29474894/4195406) for more details about creating a custom info window.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Maps SDK includes a `userData` field on the marker object, see [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#a27423edd4b4be2dc5b3124a0d816c2e4).

Using your example this is what it would look like the following to assign the data.

```
let mCustomData = customData(starRating: 10)  // init with a rating of 10

let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.snippet = "Population: 8,174,100"
london.userData = mCustomData
london.map = mapView
```

And the `customData` class something like this.

```
class customData{
    var starRating: Int
    init(starRating rating: Int) {
        starRating = rating
    }
}
```

To access the your user data just retrieve it from the marker object.

```
let mRating = (london.userData as! customData).starRating
```