# Adding Custom Info Window to Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview, google-maps-markers

I want to add a custom info window to pop up in Google Maps whenever someone taps a pin. I've already hidden the current info window by not passing it any data and know that the function

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Handles what happens when a pin is tapped. I currently have this custom UIView and attributes on my MapViewController and the corresponding outlets added to the ViewController code:
[image]

How would I implement this UIView to pop up whenever I tap a pin?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462187/creating-custom-info-window-in-swift-with-the-google-maps-ios-sdk

Comment: https://medium.com/@matschmidy/how-to-implement-custom-and-dynamic-map-marker-info-windows-for-google-maps-ios-e9d993ef46d4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use GMSMapViewDelegate to use markerInfoWindow to your class.

```
let mapview = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

mapview.delegate = self


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    // Get a reference for the custom overlay
    let index:Int! = Int(marker.accessibilityLabel!)
    let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
    customInfoWindow.Timings.text = States[index].time
    customInfoWindow.Title.text = States[index].name
    customInfoWindow.Direction_Button.tag = index
    customInfoWindow.Direction_Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GetDirectionsAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return customInfoWindow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom view for the annotation and then return that custom view for the following method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
 //Create and load your custom view here and then return the view
}
```